# Which real historical figures have been recreated on the Holodeck?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, holodeck

I was watching [VOY: Scorpion](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Scorpion_(episode)) last night. At the beginning of Part I, Captain Janeway spends some time on the Holodeck conversing with Leonardo da Vinci about his inventions and suggesting refinements.

**Who are the actual Earth history figures that have been recreated on the Holodeck in any of the Star Trek series?**

<sub>Specifically:

 - From real Earth history (as opposed to fiction in-universe history).

 - Verified as having existed.</sub>

Comment: I'm at a loss who's voted to close this as 'too broad'. It's simple and definitively answerable.

Comment: by "actual" do you mean, out of universe, our reality? (the second criteria is vaguely worded). If not, the NX crew would count thanks to Riker....

Comment: I guess that leaves out Moriarty.

Comment: TOS didn't have a newfangled holodeck but there were some historical figures, e.g. Brahms and the Earp gang.

Comment: @Spencer - Yes, moriarty is out. I attempted to post a question on fictional as well, but it got DV to oblivion.

Comment: **Captain Archer and his crew** are real historical figures on the Enterprise-D holodeck is *These are the Voyages...*   /s

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Yes, but they're only real in-universe. Which is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @Valorum, on *These are the Voyages...*, I know.   Hence the /s.   It was a comment on people taking their shows too seriously.

Comment: The title says "Which" but the question body says "How many". So what is it you are asking for, a list of names, or a number?

Comment: @user14111 an answer that just gave a number without listing the names would be very poor indeed, regardless of the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In terms of historical personages *actually seen on screen* we have;

**Albert Einstein**, **Sir Isaac Newton**, **Stephen Hawking** (TNG: Descent)
 [image]

**Sigmund Freud** (TNG: Phantasms)
 [image]

**Leonardo Da Vinci** (VOY: Scorpion, VOY: Concerning Flight, etc)
 [image]

**Mahatma Gandhi, Lord Byron, Socrates** (VOY: Darkling)
 [image]

Comment: unseen, but Sisko has baseball game holodeck programs that recreate classic teams

Comment: Related: the "real" Sir Isaac Newton was brought aboard Voyager in the episode "[Death Wish](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Wish_(episode))".

Comment: @NKCampbell - There are many programs that are *referred to but not seen*. I'm not sure whether it's worth listing them.

Comment: I think you made a mistake. That's a picture of Gimli with a green hat badly photoshopped on, not Leonardo da Vinci.

Comment: You do see a famous baseball player (forget name and episode) on screen. It's the one where their imagination becomes real.

Comment: Does Stephen Hawking count if he was played by Stephen Hawking?  Or is he the only one that counts?

Comment: @jwodder - With the exception of Socrates, I believe there's overwhelming evidence that the others existed.

Comment: @Valorum: I was referring to the fact that holo-Stephen Hawking was played by the real-world Stephen Hawking, while holo-Einstein was just played by some actor.

Comment: @jwodder - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/aside-from-stephen-hawking-were-there-any-other-as-himself-star-trek-cameos

Comment: @Valorum: Yes, I know.  That's what I was referring to.  I think you may have misinterpreted my original comment somehow.

Comment: @AytAyt: That baseball player you refer to is actually fictional. He's a player set sometime in our future who plays for a baseball team that doesn't (yet) exist.

Comment: @jwodder While Hawking is still alive in our world, he is very likely deceased when that episode takes place, making him a historical person in the context of that episode.

Comment: Is  Stephen Hawking dead ? if not, it's not a historical figure. If we take into account what Philipp said, well...still...the question does not state if historical figures from the series' perspective or our world's.

Comment: @Overmind Stephen Hawking died this year. So yes.

Comment: Finally........

Answer (score 8):

### Seen on screen

- **Albert Einstein**, besides on *Descent* as Valorum pointed out, was also recreated in *[TNG: The Nth Degree](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Nth_Degree_(episode))* by Reginald Barclay.

### Only referenced in dialogue or otherwise implied to exist

The following were not explicitly seen on screen but only referenced in dialogue, or indirectly implied to exist by the context:

- **Tris Speaker** and **Ted Williams** were two 20th century baseball players that were available on a holosuite program run by Benjamin and Jake Sisko on *[DS9: If wishes were horses](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/If_Wishes_Were_Horses_(episode))*.
- **The Three Musketeers** was a holoprogram run by Reginald Barclay on *[TNG: Hollow Pursuits](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hollow_Pursuits_(episode))*, based on the famous novel of Alexandre Dumas; real historical figures like King Louis XIII of France, Cardinal Richelieu and the Duke of Buckingham appeared on the novel, and it is safe to assume that their holographic versions were featured on the holonovel as well.
- **The Battle of the Thermopylae** was a holoprogram where Dr. Bashir wanted to carry Ezri Dax to, in *[DS9: What you leave behind](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/What_You_Leave_Behind_(episode))*. Very probably it contained real historical figures like King Leonidas.
- **The Battle of the Alamo**, similarly, was a holoprogram enjoyed by Julian Bashir and Miles O'Brien and referenced in *[DS9: Wrongs darker than death or night](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Wrongs_Darker_Than_Death_or_Night_(episode))* and *[DS9: The changing face of evil](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Changing_Face_of_Evil_(episode))*; even here, real historical characters were likely recreated.
- **The Battle of Britain**, probably the favourite holoprogram of Bashir and O'Brien, and referenced in [many episodes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_Britain).
  *<sub>If compared with the above examples, we have far less evidence that real historical figures were created in this holoprogram, that focused on the aerial battles during World War II; anyway, I think it is fair to suppose that the appeal to run historical holoprograms was not just to live in another era but also to interact with real historical figures; and another supposition of mine without any reference, but I like to think that B&O'B ran that program not just for actual airplane battles, but also for the supposed briefing/debriefing/aftermath parts, where they could have had the chance to meet some real historical figure.</sub>*

## Bonus: impersonated by crew members

The following historical figures were not recreated by actual holograms, but were impersonated by crew members **inside a holoprogram**:

- **Henry V of England** was impersonated by Data in *[TNG: The Defector](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Defector_(episode))*.

Comment: There's no good indication that the Battle of Britain program contained any real life figures. The only person referred to is "Clive".

Comment: No, there is no evidence, hence my "very probably" statements; I think it is fair to suppose that the appeal to run historical holoprograms was not just to live in another era but also to interact with real historical figures; another supposition of mine without any reference, but I like to think that B&O'B run that program not just for the airplane battles, but also for the supposed briefing/debriefing/aftermath parts, where they could have had the chance to meet someone (maybe even being decorated by Churchill himself :D)

Answer (score 3):

Seriously, kids these days.

*Star Trek: TOS* didn't have any newfangled,  highfalutin' holler-decks. Instead we had to make do with historical figures living through to Starfleet times, or with aliens recreating famous people to try to kill Kirk, Spock, McCoy, and various red shirts.

Ahem. Anyway, since you specifically allowed TOS:

- In **"[Spectre of the Gun](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_of_the_Gun)"** (season 3, episode 6) aliens re-create the Gunfight at the OK Corral...well, sort of, but at least we get to see **[Wyatt Earp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wyatt_Earp)** and his brothers **[Virgil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgil_Earp)** and **[Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morgan_Earp)**, **[Doc Holliday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doc_Holliday)**, and Sherriff **[Johnny Behan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Behan)**.
- In **"[Requiem for Methusaleh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requiem_for_Methuselah)"** (season 3, episode 19), we get **[Solomon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon)**, **[Alexander the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_the_Great)**, **[Leonardo da Vinci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_da_Vinci)**, **[Johannes Brahms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Brahms)**, and others, courtesy of the long-lived "Mr. Flint".
- In **"[The Savage Curtain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Savage_Curtain)"** (season 3, episode 22) we get **[Abraham Lincoln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Lincoln)** and **[Genghis Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genghis_Khan)** recreated by aliens for Kirk and Spock to fight with/against.
- Finally, in **"[Who Mourns for Adonais?](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Mourns_for_Adonais%3F)"** (season 2, episode 2) we have an edge case: the Greek god **[Apollo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo)**, who although arguably not a real person, certainly affected history as the focus of ancient Greek cults, especially the Oracle at Delphi.

Believe me, the "[holodeck episode](https://io9.gizmodo.com/5280450/star-treks-absolute-worst-holodeck-adventures)" was invented long before the holodeck.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question asked (e.g. which ones appear on the **holodeck**). You've invented your own question and then answered it.

Comment: @Valorum Oh for Pete's sake, OP's original text of the question said "any Star Trek series" and specifically allowed TOS. It was your own edit that changed it, because you wanted to emphasize the holodeck over the appearance of historical characters. It can be argued that it was you who invented their own question.

Comment: I'd leave off Apollo because he was supposed to be the original being, not a recreation. @Valorum According to the letter of the question, yes, this answer doesn't directly address it. However, this isn't Server Fault where straying slightly from the original question results in an insecure server or Stack Overflow where it results in subtly broken programs. I think this answer stays within the *spirit* of the question (fake recreations of historical figures) and provides some related information that is likely to interest people wondering about the original question.

Comment: Per the original question "**how many actual Earth history figures have been recreated on the holodeck?**". I didn't change the focus of the question, I merely bolded and highlighted it. If the question was "*What historical figures do we ever see in Star Trek"*, there'd be scope to add dozens more.

Comment: This answer is clearly off-topic, the question was crystalline clear in asking specifically about the holodeck and not about general appearances of historical characters, even in its first unedited version.

Comment: He didn't ask about the "holodeck episode" though.

Comment: Shout out to Apollo in: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102947/in-star-trek-do-the-greek-gods-lack-nipples

Comment: There's a mistake in the linked [*worst holodeck episodes*](https://io9.gizmodo.com/5280450/star-treks-absolute-worst-holodeck-adventures) list; The VOY episode ***The Thaw*** (with the clown) didn't happen on a holodeck, so it shouldn't be in there. Jus saying.